# How can l put TableView inside CollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, collectionview

I have a tableView with several cells (created by MVVM-architecture).

In ViewController I fill my tableView like this:

```
tbv.registerCells(
        withModels:
        FirstViewModel.self,
        SecondViewModel.self,
        ThirdViewModel.self)
```

My task is to put my TableView in one cell of CollectionView. I thought l have to create CollectionView in my ViewController, after it create CollectionViewCell and CollectionCellViewModel, but how to do it exactly I don't understand.

If you know, how to make it, help.

Comment: Ar you creating this in SwiftUI or in UIKit? I can show you how I did it in UIKit, but have no working examples for SwiftUI.

Comment: @MacUserT in UIKit. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Maytime, when it's the correct answer, please, click that it is the right answer. Just giving a notch up doesn't give me the required points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I have several tableviews in collection views in one of my apps. First I have a view controller in which I build my collection view. As usually proposed in the new design guidelines, I have the Collection View delegate and data source in an extension of this view controller.

In your view controller you define a delegate and data source for your table view. Preferably, this is a different class. I would not have the tableview data source and delegate also in the same view controller as your collection view.

```
class WorkoutSettingsViewController: UIViewController, LoadWorkoutSettings {

    //MARK: - Properties
    //Used variables

    //Used constants
    private let settingsDelegate = SettingsTableViewDelegate()
```

The extension would then look like this.

```
extension WorkoutSettingsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //Whatever sets your sections
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Whatever sets your rows per section
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Workout Settings", for: indexPath) as! SettingsCollectionViewCell
            
        settingsDelegate.workoutTitleLabel = [countdown, mainView, spokenMessage]
        settingsDelegate.mainContentLabel = getSettingsContent()
        cell.settingsTableView.delegate = settingsDelegate
        cell.settingsTableView.dataSource = settingsDelegate
        cell.settingsTableView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
     //Whatever you need as header or footer
}
```

The delegate does exactly what you would like the table view data source and delegate to do.

```
class SettingsTableViewDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    //Used variables
    var workoutTitleLabel = [String]()
    var mainContentLabel = [String]()
    var selectedSetting: ((Int) -> ())? = .none
    private var secondaryContentLabel = [String]()
    
    //Used constants
    private let onTitle = NSLocalizedString("ON", comment: "Localized on title")
    private let offTitle = NSLocalizedString("OFF", comment: "Localized off title")
    private let fontColorBlack = UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 19.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    private let fontColorRed = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 96.0/255.0, blue: 89.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        workoutTitleLabel.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Settings Cell") as! WorkoutTableViewCell
        
        cell.workoutTitle.text = workoutTitleLabel[indexPath.row]
        cell.mainContent.text = mainContentLabel[indexPath.row]
        cell.secondaryContent.text = ""
        
        (mainContentLabel[indexPath.row] == offTitle) ? (cell.mainContent.textColor = fontColorRed) : (cell.mainContent.textColor = fontColorBlack)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        selectedSetting?(indexPath.row)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        61
    }
}
```

Your collection view cell should look like this.

```
class SettingsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsTableView: UITableView!
}
```

This should then work. If you need to have a callback from the table view delegate / data source to your view controller managing your collection view, you can use a closure. In the example table view delegate the closure is called selectedSettings. In your view controller in viewDidLoad you define the call back for instance like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    settingsDelegate.selectedSetting = { [unowned self] selection in
        startSettingsMenu(for: selection)
    }
    
}
```

The result looks like this.
[image]

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Answer (score 0):

In Tableview each row you can load **UITableViewCell** with pass **collectionviewdata**

```
//View Controller

var collectionView1Data = ["cell1", "cell2"]
var collectionView2Data = ["cell1", "cell2"]

//UITableviewDelegate Datasource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //.....
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as? TableviewCell
        cell.collectionData = collectionView1Data /// Collectionviewdata 
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as? TableviewCell
        cell.collectionData = collectionView2Data
        return cell
    }
}
```

============================== 
Each **Tableviewcell** contains **CollectionView**

```
//UITableViewCell
class TableviewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var collectionData: [String]? {
        didSet {
            guard collectionData != nil else {
                return
            }
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "collectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension TableviewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        collectionData.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? collectionViewCell
        cell...
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but l don't use either dataSouce/delegates, l have to do it in my MVVM-architecture way + with rxSwift. But l think your answer will be good for another guys!