# Does UIHostingController have to be in the view controller hierarchy?

Tags: swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I want to embed some SwiftUI in my UIKit-based UI, and unfortunately Apple doesn't provide `UIHostingView`, only `UIHostingController`. Can I more or less ignore that controller and just use its view, or do I really need to add it as a child view controller as well? What happens if I don't?

The problem is that finding the parent view controller can be difficult in some contexts. `UIView` itself doesn't know anything about view controllers, so I'd have to come up with my own way of keeping track of which is the "current" view controller. And I'd rather not do that unless it's actually necessary.

So far in my experiments it's working fine without adding `UIHostingController` as a child. Device rotation is handled appropriately, and SwiftUI's dark mode override (`.colorScheme()`) even works through the embedding.

Answer (score 0):

With `UIHostingController(rootView:)` you just pass in a SwiftUI `View`.

You can treat it as a `UIView` by doing:

```
let myView = UIHostingController(rootView: Text("Hello world!")).view
```

And then add it as a subview for example:

```
let parent = UIView()
parent.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: The question is, what are the consequences of ignoring the view controller? Presumably there is a reason why AppKit has `NSHostingView` while UIKit does not have `UIHostingView'. But it's not really obvious why that is.

Comment: @Uncommon Interesting question. I stumbled upon [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56827040/9607863) and I am unsure as to why they do `addChild(controller)`. I have used the `UIView` directly, and I don't specifically see a reason why it isn't reasonable to use. It could be so they can access the [`children`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-children) of the view controller, but I am honestly not 100% sure on this. It is an interesting point. What I would say is if all you need is the view, this will work. Do correct me if you find good reasons to!

Comment: It is in place in order to coordinate the lifecycle of the child view controller. How would the child viewcontroller otherwise know whether it has appeared/disappeared

Comment: does this actually work? I don't see Hello World appear at all